# Noisy Dell Rack UPS 1000W

Tags: dell, ups

Just installed our new DELL Rack UPS 1000W and its very noisy. The fans are always spinning even with nothing attached and with the UPS turned off.

Will they one day slow down or stop spinning? We have the rack enclosure in the office and can't almost talk with each other because of the noise of this unit.

Comment: After 72 hours the server is silent when no load is applied. I still have to figure out why.

Comment: If it's new and you think it's noisier than it should be have you considered talking to Dell about it?

Answer (score 12):

1. server room equipment is usually not meant to be set up in an office
2. why not call Dell and ask this question - maybe the unit is misconfigured, or has some sort of acoustic mode setting
3. ## 2 doesn't cancel #1 of course.

Comment: +1 for rack equipment isn't meant to be out in the open in an office. It's generally more robust equipment at the expense of frivolities like being pretty or quiet like something that's meant to sit on a desk.  Though it shouldn't be deafening.

Comment: wrt "shouldn't be deafening" - have you tried standing next to a fully loaded blade chassis?

Comment: The aforementioned UPS shouldn't be deafening.  Definitely plenty of other deafening equipment!

Comment: you might be right, but I wouldn't hazard such a statement, unless I'd been an expert on this particular equipment. Which I'm not